# SQL Server Agent permissions versus user permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I am setup as an admin on our SQL Server 2012 and I have created a job that runs a procedure that selects records from 2 joined tables. This all works fine when I am logged into SSMS and manually launch the job. The problem is when I try to schedule the job to run (even if I am still logged into SSMS) the same job does not return records from the second table, it is like the join does not work.

I checked and the SQL agent is using the main SQL Server service account which I am assuming would have rights to everything.

Any thoughts on trouble shooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Any hints in the job history?

Comment: @artm, no error message because the job runs fine - the data is just incomplete.  If I manually start the job from SSMS I get data from both tables, if I schedule it ignores the join and only returns half the data.

Answer (score 2):

On the Steps page of the sql job you can tell it to "Run As" a particular user.

Otherwise, the account that the SQL Server Agent runs under would have to have rights to all databases/tables, etc.

You should be able to see what's happening when the job runs on a schedule by viewing the job history.  You do this by right-clicking either the job in your list of jobs or by right-clicking the job in the Job Monitor and selecting 'View History'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I manually run the procedure with no RunAs - no issue.  When I manually run the job (that runs the same procedure) with no RunAs - no issue.  When I schedule the job with no RunAs setup it gives me only half the data with no errors.  (We do use pass-through authentication) and when I try to put my credentials in the RunAs box - it fails to even run manually and gives error:  Server user '%.*ls' is not a valid user in database '%.*ls'.  This security is confusing me.

Comment: Has the database been recently moved from another server?  Please see this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240872/how-to-resolve-permission-issues-when-you-move-a-database-between-servers-that-are-running-sql-server

Comment: Apart from the info in the article I mentioned before, you, or another administrator, should check the server login and database user that you plan to use to run the job on a regular basis.

Quick question: are the 2 joined tables in the same database?

We would usually use what we called a 'service account'; usually a SQL Login that has db_owner rights on the database.  

You could set one up as a test, to verify that it works, then fine-tune the security settings later.

Comment: hasn't recently moved, and it is 2 separate databases - actually 6 on the same instance.  We don't do a lot of SQL work and was thinking about just leaving it using my account.

Comment: Since you're an administrator on that server, you should be able to create a SQL Login, unless your sql server is only set up to use Windows authentication, in which case you will have to use a Windows account.

Either way, you create the Login under the Security folder of the main tree 
- right-click Logins
- New Login
- General page: for Windows login click Search to locate user account
- For SQL Login, enter a meaningful name and password
- Un-check 'User must change pw...'
- Leave Default Database as 'master'
- User Mapping page: tick db's; dbo as default schema

Comment: - Tick db_owner in bottom pane for each db
Click OK button.
This will add the new login to each of the selected databases by creating a user on each that is linked to the login you just added.

Comment: Tried another SQL account with sysadmin server role and still only get half the data and no errors with scheduler.  Yet this job still works when I manually start it??  I am starting to miss Oracle lol.

Comment: As a side note - when I check the history, running job manually and using scheduler both are using the same admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Was a corrupt job.  I deleted the job and recreated a new one and it worked as expected.